# Loading TensorFlow.js model from File Server

Tags: tensorflow.js, fileserver

I am trying to load Tensorflow.js model via HTTP protocol. Tensorflow.js requires me to store 'model.json' and 'weights.bin' files in the same folder. But I can only call 'model.json' as a parameter. It refers to the binary file by itself. That is how it works as far as I know.

For now, in the local environment, I am loading the model from the localhost(Http://127.0.0.1:8080) and it works fine.

However, the actual application accepts HTTPS protocol only. So I have tried to store them with models and weights in the same buckets in S3 and called via Lambda but it seems like only 'model.json' is retrieved. I am thinking of using EC2 instances where the Python Flask server is running but it seems like the same that only model.json is retrieved, not binary files.

Is there any way that I can retrieve 'model.json' with referring to the weight file? Is there anyway to host file server remotely with HTTPS protocol?

Answer (score 1):

**TFJS** downloads model `JSON`, parses it and uses whatever paths are specified in the JSON - you can edit that file and set any URL you want for weights.

Alternatively, you can also use lower-level methods to load weights manually (in case you want to have a custom loader, etc.), but leave that for future until you're more comfortable with TFJS.